# Declines Vs Declineth

Tags: verb-forms, subjunctives, archaic-language

> Declines Vs Declineth

Somewhere I read that "decline" is just third person , but "declineth" is indicative .

Could you help me explain the difference of indicative with some examples so that I elicit the point.

Comment: That's incorrect.  There is no contrast between third person and indicative. You're asking about inflectional affixes from Early Modern English and earlier forms of the language; *declineth* doesn't exist in Modern English.

Answer (score 5):

**Declines** and **declineth** are both third-person singular indicative.

**Declineth** is archaic, or [Early Modern English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Modern_English). **Declineth** is found in the King James bible: "My days are like a shadow that declineth, and I am withered like grass." (Psalm 102) That's in the indicative mood: just describing something, not treating it as a hypothesis or alternate reality.

In the 1500s, people said both **declines** and **declineth** to mean the same thing. There was no grammatical distinction, but **declines** was felt to be informal and **declineth** appropriate for ordinary or formal speech, and for poetry. [[source](https://books.google.com/books?id=CCvMbntWth8C&pg=PA164)]

The [subjunctive mood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive), in all persons and numbers, both modern and archaic, is **decline**. The subjunctive mood means that the verb describes a hypothetical, desired, or proposed reality, distinguished from what really is or was. For example, "Jones requires that Smith decline all further offers." When people use the verb **require**, they often put the subordinate clause's verb in the subjunctive mood. In Early Modern English, the same sentence might be: "Jones requireth that Smith declyne all forther offers." (Spelling wasn't very standardized back then. It could just as easily have been "decline all further offers".) [[source](https://books.google.com/books?id=CCvMbntWth8C&pg=PA228)]

Usually when a verb is put into the subjunctive mood, it's in a subordinate clause, as in the **requires** examples. But not always. A well-known sentence with the main verb in the subjunctive mood is "God bless you". Here, the subjunctive mood expresses a wish. In the indicative mood, it would be "God blesses you", making a claim about what is happening now.

It's hard to find the subjunctive mood in modern English because in all conjugations of a verb except the third-person singular, the indicative and subjunctive moods have exactly the same form. To illustrate, the first sentence in each of the following pairs has **sleep** in the indicative mood; the second sentence has **sleep** in the subjunctive mood:

> I sleep at night. / The doctor recommends that I sleep. [first-person singular]
>
> We sleep at night. / The doctor recommends that we sleep. [first-person plural]
>
> You sleep at night. / The doctor recommends that you sleep. [second person]
>
> **He sleeps** at night. / The doctor recommends that **he sleep**. [third person singular]
>
> They sleep at night. / The doctor recommends that they sleep. [third-person plural]

As you can see, in the present tense, the subjunctive always has the same form as the infinitive.

There is only one verb that has a distinct form for the subjunctive mood in the past tense, and that's **be**. The subjunctive past tense of **be** is **were** in all persons and numbers. It usually shows up following **if**: "If I were you…", "If we were young again…", "If you were rich…", "If he were smarter…", "If they were home now…" As you can see, the subjunctive past tense doesn't necessarily refer to the past!